Single docker image for my reactjs v18 using azure devops pipeline
Our front end is react v18. We are using azure devops to create docker image.  I am not able to create docker image that will run on say dev  qa, pre prod, prod environments. Is this not feasible.  ?
Discussed other teams seems it s not achievable

It will be better if you showed what you tried or maybe why you came to the conclusion that it is not feasible

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

May I assume you would build docker image with pipeline task? If yes, can you please share your minimal and reproducible code like docker file and pipeline YAML definition to help understand your workflow and expectations? What was the error and in which pipeline you observed it? Can you please describe your issue with some screenshots? We are unable to know everything based on such limited information. Thx.
